# Default info window is not available after configuring marker touch in Google Maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am developing a google map app. I have provided a label at the bottom of the app to display the name and distance of atm that i display on the map with the help of markers. At first when I was tapping the markers by default it was showing the name of the atm in the marker info but after that I included this function to get the distance of the particular atm from the user location-

```
- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
//for getting users current location co-ordinates
        latitudess=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        float latt=[latitudess floatForKey:@"LATITUDE"];
        float longg=[latitudess floatForKey:@"LONGITUDE"];



    CLLocationCoordinate2D cord= CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latt, longg);
    CLLocationDistance distance= GMSGeometryDistance(cord, marker.position);

    labelToShowCurrentRadiusValue.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",distance];
}
```

And hence from now the default map info which displayed the title of the marker is not available which usually displayed the name of the atm is not visible.

But I want it to be visible. So why this thing is being caused and what should I do in order to display the info again?

Answer (score 1):

Any guys searching for answers to such problem. The answer is you should type `return NO;`

because if you are returning YES, you are asking the function to change the default map features on tapping the marker and we don't wan to do such thing here.